# What familiars in Runescape will bank items for you?

Tags: runescape

In Runescape what familiars will bank your items for you? I'm doing steel dragons and want to get the steel bars (they're worth 1k each) to my bank so I don't feel like I'm cutting my total profit short. So, what familliars can help me and what level(s) do I need to use them?

I know you can bank using a pack yak will bank 30 items and a legendary pet will bank one item. Anything else?

Comment: Why is this down-voted so hard?

Comment: @tQuarella Beats me.

Answer (score 5):

There is only one **familiar** which can deposit items from your inventory to the bank. The [Pack yak](https://runescape.wiki/w/Pack_yak). It requires 96 summoning and, with a Winter Storage scroll, you can bank an item from anywhere.

However, there are three **pets** from the Solomon's General Store which have an ability to bank items. Note that these pets cost 1300 runecoins for free to play players, or 1170 runecoins for members.

---

Although this will not help you, the [abyssal titan](https://runescape.wiki/w/Abyssal_titan) has a special move which banks all essence from its Beast of Burden and your inventory to the bank. However, this is only limited to essence, so it won't help with your steel bars. It also needs 93 summoning to summon and the scroll uses 6 points.

Comment: @Hadrio That's wrong you can also bank one item using legendary pets when they reach a mature age.

Comment: @YoungGuilo Legendary pets? Oh, you mean the pets from the Solomon's General Store?

Comment: Why the downvote please

Comment: I downvoted because I already know about the pack yak and the legendary pets. You just saying it again in an answer doesn't help me.

Comment: @YoungGuilo there is no other familiar or pet

Comment: then that should be your answer.

Comment: @YoungGuilo I said that...

Comment: @YoungGuilo Haidro put that as his original answer, and you defiantly denying his answer doesn't help anyone.  He had stated there were no other ones other than the one you mentioned, and now you accuse him of making an answer for nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Only the Pack Yak has the 'Winter Storage' ability to send it's inventory to your bank. The Abyssal Titan can send all pure and rune essences in your inventory and it's own to the bank with it's 'Essence Shipment' ability. No other familiar abilities send items directly to the bank.

Source: https://runescape.wiki/w/Summoning_familiars

Comment: We prefer actual answers rather than links to answers. Can you summarize what is behind that link?

Comment: You gave me a link that doesn't even answer my question. I know that a pack yak can bank items for you. I'm looking for others.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize that links were inadequate. Summarized, better?